# BNF for comma separated sequence?

Tags: grammar, bnf

Can't come up with a BNF grammar for the sequence of characters (possibly empty), separated by comma, but not starting or ending with a comma,

So this is OK:

```
  <--- Empty sequence is ok!
A
A,B
A,B,C
```

This is NOT ok:

```
A,
,A
A,,B
AB
```

The empty case throws me off. What I got so far is:

```
<char-seq> ::= <empty> | <char> , <char-seq> | <char>
```

but this produces strings like `A,` :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The empty char sequence is what gives you the trouble. You need a rule that matches a non-empty sequence to be separate from the rule that matches both an empty and a non-empty one, like this:

```
<char-seq> ::= <empty> | <non-empty-char-seq>
<non-empty-char-seq> ::= <char> | <char> , <non-empty-char-seq>
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but I think  this BNF is infinite recursive ? it should be like that <non-empty-char-seq> ::= /*empty*/|<char> | <char> , <non-empty-char-seq> am i right ?

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş The `<empty>` is allowed by `<char-seq>`, but not by `<non-empty-char-seq>`, which must start and end in a character.

Answer (score 4):

```
<char-seq> ::= <empty> | <chars>
<chars> ::= <char> | <char> , <chars>
```